# Prevent drag of local code/items from triggering dragenter

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, fileapi

Im building an HTML5 file upload, and I want to have the dragenter fire when the user drags a file over the window. The idea is that dragenter will triger a lightbox style overlay, showing the drop zone.

here is my code. (jQuery)

```
$(window).bind('dragenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#uploadWrapper').show();
}).bind('dragexit', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#uploadWrapper').hide();
});
```

this works fine, but if the user grabs an image or some texts and drags it, it also trigers, the dragenter event. Is there a way I can tell what is being dragged so only actual files to upload trigger showing the overlay?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like the following should work; (Though I don't think it's Opera friendly.)

```
function DraggedFiles(e)
{
    for (n in e.dataTransfer.types)
    {
        if (e.dataTransfer.types[n] === "Files") return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Then, for your `dragEnter` event, just add:

```
if (DraggedFiles(e))
{
    // files were dragged onto here
} else {
    // something other than files were dragged
}
```

where you want to make the check and do action/inaction.

Comment: Sadly it seems that e.dataTransfer is undefined in the dragenter event. 

`jQuery(window).bind('dragenter', function (e) {
 console.log(e.dataTransfer);
    })`

Comment: Ahh, It's jQuery causing the problem...you'll need to access it by event.originalEvent.dataTransfer, I think: [Event Object - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Scroll down to the "Other Properties" section.

Comment: YA! That was it! Feel stupid now, as I should have spotted that! Also small typo in your code at `for(n in...` should have been `for(i in...`